# Jenkins does not build my ant project

Tags: ant, jenkins, continuous-integration, phpunit, build-automation

I've just started with Jenkins and I'm just trying to use it to execute phpunit tests.

My steps are: create the file build.xml as [here](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.3/en/build-automation.html) says:

```
<project name="mbp2" default="build">
 <target name="clean">
  <delete dir="${basedir}/build"/>
 </target>

 <target name="prepare">
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/logs"/>
 </target>

 <target name="phpunit">
  <exec dir="${basedir}" executable="phpunit">
   <arg line="-c app --log-junit ${basedir}/build/logs/phpunit.xml src/MyFirm/FrontendBundle/Tests" />
  </exec>
 </target>

 <target name="build" depends="clean,prepare,phpunit"/>
</project>
```

So, I executed ant and I got this:

> javier@javier-mbp:~/programacion/mbp/myfirm$ ant Buildfile:
>   /home/javier/programacion/mbp/myfirm/build.xml
>
> clean:    [delete] Deleting directory
>   /home/javier/programacion/mbp/myfirm/build
>
> prepare:
>       [mkdir] Created dir: /home/javier/programacion/mbp/myfirm/build/logs
>
> phpunit:
>        [exec] PHPUnit 3.6.4 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>        [exec] 
>        [exec] Configuration read from /home/javier/programacion/mbp/myfirm/app/phpunit.xml
>        [exec] 
>        [exec] ...............
>        [exec] 
>        [exec] Time: 6 seconds, Memory: 157.50Mb
>        [exec] 
>               OK (15 tests, 18 assertions)
>
> build:
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 6 seconds

Then I created a new job in Jenkins choosing as git repository as below:

> file:///home/javier/programacion/mbp/myfirm/

Finally I built the project, so I expected to see the same output as when I executed `ant` without Jenkins, but nothing about that..

In the "Console Output" section showed as below:

> Started by user anonymous Checkout:workspace /
>   /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mbp2/workspace -
>   hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@76996f0c Using strategy: Default Last
>   Built Revision: Revision 9aafeea09cdb23317f2426f8209c75341565c070
>   (origin/HEAD, origin/master) Checkout:workspace /
>   /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/mbp2/workspace -
>   hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@76996f0c Fetching changes from 1 remote
>   Git repository Fetching upstream changes from
>   file:///home/javier/programacion/mbp/myfirm Seen branch in repository
>       origin/HEAD Seen branch in repository origin/master Commencing build of Revision 9aafeea09cdb23317f2426f8209c75341565c070
>   (origin/HEAD, origin/master) Checking out Revision
>   9aafeea09cdb23317f2426f8209c75341565c070 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
>   Warning : There are multiple branch changesets here Finished: SUCCESS

Javier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an `Ant` build step. Jenkins doesn't do anything you don't tell it to.

Answer (score 1):

Ant configuration in Jenkins:

1. Run Jenkins and browse it
2. Click the link of your project/job name --> Click Configure link at the left
3. Click "Add build step" combo and select "Invoke Ant" from combo
4. Fill up necessary fields for Ant configuration and save it

OR, You can execute ant.bat in Windows as below instead of "Invoke Ant":

1. Run Jenkins and browse it
2. Click the link of your project/job name --> Click Configure link at the left
3. Click "Add build step" combo and select "Execute Windows batch command" from combo
4. Write the proper command (In my case it was: C:\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin\ant.bat) and save it